# Изменение записи в MySQL средствами php

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать следующее:

```
$text = "тролололо";
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET text=`text`+$text");
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET text=CONCAT(text, '$text');");
```

вроде как)